# How to setup onFocusChangeListener() on a dynamically created set of editTexts?

Tags: android, dynamic, runtime, android-linearlayout

i have this code in which i inflate a linearLayout containing 3 editTexts everytime an edittext of the previous lineaLayout loses focus. I want to have the onFocusChangeListener on the most recent created editTexts only. Instead, onFocusChangeListener is called only when the the first linearLayout loses focus and not the rest of others.

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.sale_purchase_vouch);
    no=0;
    for(int i=0;i<30;i++)
        flag[i]=true;

    save=(Button)findViewById(R.id.Save);
    save.setText("Confirm Purchase");
    LayoutInflater l=getLayoutInflater();
    container=(LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.container);
    row[no]=(LinearLayout)l.inflate(R.layout.row, container);
    items[no]=(AutoCompleteTextView)row[no].findViewById(R.id.item);
    quants[no]=(EditText)row[no].findViewById(R.id.quant);
    rates[no]=(EditText)row[no].findViewById(R.id.rate);

    quants[no].setOnFocusChangeListener(this);
    flag[no]=false;


}


@Override
public void onFocusChange(View arg0, boolean arg1) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    if(flag[no+1]==true){

        if(arg1==false){
            no++;
    LayoutInflater g=getLayoutInflater();

    row[no]=(LinearLayout)g.inflate(R.layout.row, container);
    items[no]=(AutoCompleteTextView)row[no].findViewById(R.id.item);
    quants[no]=(EditText)row[no].findViewById(R.id.quant);
    rates[no]=(EditText)row[no].findViewById(R.id.rate);
    Log.d("detection", "Row is "+ no+ arg0.getId());
        }
    }
}
```

I created an array of boolean to know whether the last editText had created a new linearLayout(listened to the onFocusChangeListener). help!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to extend the `EditText` class so you create your own type of `View` where might want to have an inner class which will implement [View.OnFocusChangeListener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.OnFocusChangeListener.html) and `public` method so you can setup listener with an instance of this inner class using the instance of newly created type.

Comment: yeah, you are right but just look at the code and explain how to implement it. I have already tried by using 'quants[no].setOnFocusChangeListener(this);'. So the value of 'no' should setup the listener for every editText of quants array (quants[no])

Comment: If you would implement it using the way I described you will have each and every EditText instance has it's own listener object.

Comment: I tried but i could not find a way to solve this just like you told me. Can you post an example for I can get in the right direction