# onFocusChangeListener on EditText created at runtime

Tags: android, runtime, android-edittext, onfocus

I want to setup an onFocusChangeListener() on a dynamically created editText. The function of the listener would be the same for all the editTexts that is creating a same kind of editText. Once an editText has created another editText it should stop listening to onFocusChange.

Note: I know that I have already asked this question but I couldn't find a solution
[How to setup onFocusChangeListener() on a dynamically created set of editTexts?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18258875/how-to-setup-onfocuschangelistener-on-a-dynamically-created-set-of-edittexts)

Comment: Couple of things: what exactly is the problem you're experiencing? Also, it's probably worth adding a link to your previous question, otherwise you may end with the same suggestions again.

Comment: @MH http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18258875/how-to-setup-onfocuschangelistener-on-a-dynamically-created-set-of-edittexts